# how to list autostart application or services in ubuntu server

Tags: server

I have an ubuntu server and i need to know a list services and application that autostart in ubuntu server, is there a way to do this ?

till today I do it manually by checking in `htop` after I restarted the server and take note application that is starting, I know this seems dumb, I hope there is a better way to do this.

Comment: another -1 without telling me what's wrong with the question ~~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the initctl list command to list the contents of /etc/init.

Comment: thanks bro that solve it, exactly what i was looking for